# Is it possible to host Silverlight app inside Java Applet?

Tags: java, silverlight, plugins, applet

I know that is possible to display **HTML** documents using the **showDocument** method of the **java.applet.AppletContext** class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).
Is it possible to show HTML document, which has hosted Silverlight app?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `showDocument` method does not open the HTML **in the applet**, but a (tab of) **the browser**.

In its simplest form, it replaces the page containing the applet, with the URL supplied.  When a `target` is defined, the URL will be opened in that named tab.